# Специализация шаблонного метода от шаблонного класса

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

Pr.S. Даже и незнаю уже что гуглить, ничего подходящего не найду:

Имеется класс-менеджер в котором хранятся некоторые объекты, для хранения выбран класс `std::set` в классе будет несколько контейнеров:

```
typedef std::set<FrameSelection*> FrameSet; // UPD

class SelectionManager {
    FrameSet frames_;
    FooSet foo_;
    ...
    template < template<typename> class C, class TContextRepresented>
        C<TContextRepresented* > *
        getSelectionSetPtr() { return 0; }

    ...
};
```

В зависимсости от специализации метода я хочу возвращать нужный контейнер для специализированного типа :

```
template <> std::set< FrameSelection* >*
    SelectionManager::getSelectionSetPtr
                        < std::set<FrameSelection*>, FrameSelection >() {
        return &frames_;
    }
```

при сборке компилятор выдает следующую ошибку:

```
 selectionmanager.cpp:25: ошибка: template-id 'getSelectionSetPtr<std::set<FrameSelection*>, FrameSelection>' for 'std::set<FrameSelection*>* SelectionManager::getSelectionSetPtr()' does not match any template declaration
```

Что мне можно почитать про это? И как правильно определить специализацию?

Comment: "Суть проблемы в том, что я не определял специализацию метода как inline..." - не существует никаких причин определять специализацию метода как `inline`, т.е. "сутью проблемы" это быть никак не может. Более того, вы умдрились засунуть определения `inline` методов в .cpp файл, что заведомо неправильно (если только вы не включаете его как хедер).

Comment: Понятно, что ключевое слово inline как и все ключевые слова для методов должны использоваться в определении класса, тем не менее на mingw все работает, а без него(слова) нет, конечно я не знаю во что это транслируется, но ведь это спецификации шаблоных методов, и компилятор не дал бы определить новый метод для класса вне его определения. И не пропустил бы возврат указателя на атрибут этого класса. Если бы это был не его метод.

Comment: если реализация метода описана внутри определения класса, то метод принимается как inline

Comment: @AnT https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/templates#template-specialization-example

Comment: Это все замечательно, но еще раз: рассматриваемый вам вопрос никакого отношения к inline не имеет. Вы можете сделать это с inline, можете - без inline. Тема inline и тема специализации метода - совершенно ортогональные темы, никак друг с другом не связанные. Поэтому нет никакого смысла даже упоминать inline в рамках данного вопроса - это лишь замусоривает изложение иррелевантными деталями.

Answer (score 5):

Вы используете шаблон-параметр шаблона, значит при специализации должен быть указан шаблон:

```
template <>
std::set<FrameSelection*>*
SelectionManager::getSelectionSetPtr<std::set, FrameSelection>() {
                                  // ^^^^^^^^
    return &frames_;
}
```

Т.е. для шаблона с параметром `template<template<class> class X>`
надо писать `<std::set>` а не `<std::set<Y>>`,
потому что аргумент - это шаблон `std::set`, а не конкретный тип `std::set<Y>`.

---

Однако на этом проблемы не заканчиваются. У `std::set` не один, а несколько шаблонных аргументов, по этому в объявлении шаблона надо перечислить их все.

Либо, в качестве костыля можно использовать псевдоним `std::set`, у которого будет один шаблонный агрумент:

```
template<typename T> using MySet = std::set<T>;

template <>
MySet< FrameSelection* >*
SelectionManager::getSelectionSetPtr<MySet, FrameSelection>() {
    return &frames_;
}
```

Comment: Все та же ошибка я определил тип от шаблона, посмотрите выше я поправил код (первая строка первого блока)  если даже указать возвращаемый тип FrameSet, то выдается она же

Comment: Да я не ясно выразился видимо, возвращай хоть `std::set<FrameSelection*>*`, хоть `FrameSet*` - ошибка одна и та же.

Comment: `template <> std::set<FrameSelection*>* // FrameSet* - без разницы
    SelectionManager::getSelectionSetPtr
                        < std::set, FrameSelection >() {
        return &frames_;
    }` все та же ошибка...

Comment: Пробовал не помогает, линковщик говорит что я переопределяю метод getSelectionSetPtr курю cppreference

Comment: Действительно, но ведь и не догадался, что нужно было как сказано в учебниках, просто если специализирован шаблон, думал толку от того что он инлайновый не будет, пожалуйста обновите ответ, или я обновлю вопрос, помечу ваш как верный.

Answer (score -1):

Если кратко о шаблонах в С++, то они применяются по следующей схеме.

1) Есть структура данных.

```
typedef struct {
   short length;
   char data[];
} String;
```

2) Есть функция. Например, возвращающая подстроку.

```
void subString(const String* str, String* substr);
```

3) Это был С, переходим к С с объектами. Создадим класс, чтобы сделать код читабельнее и реюзабельнее.

```
class String {
   protected:
      short m_length;
      char m_data[];
   public:
      void subString(String* substr) const;
};
```

4) А теперь перейдём к С++. Почему длина обязательно типа short, может быть нам в проекте понадобятся более длинные строки? И почему тип символов обязатеельно char, может быть нам потребуется строки Unicode?

Поэтому превращаем класс в шаблон.

```
template <typename LengthT, typename CharT>
class StringT {
   protected:
      LengthT m_length;
      CharT m_data[];
   public:
      void subString(StringT* substr);
};
```

И объявляем наш класс как

```
typedef StringT<short, char> String;
```

Применительно к данной задаче. Объектов много разных типов, а функция одна. В качестве селектора - тип объекта. Следовательно, нужен класс-функтор.

```
template <class T>
class Get {
      std::set<T*> *m_pSet;
   public:
      Get(std::set<T*>& pSet) : m_pSet(&pSet) {}
      std::set<T*>* operator () (void) { return m_pSet; }
};
```

Теперь

```
class SelectionManager {
      typedef std::set<int*> IntSet;
      typedef std::set<float*> FloatSet;
      IntSet m_intSet;
      FloatSet m_floatSet;
   public:
      template <class T> std::set<T*>* getSelectionSetPtr() const {
         Get<T> get((std::set<T*>) *this);
         return get();
      }
      inline IntSet& operator IntSet () { return m_intSet; }
      inline FloatSet& operator FloatSet () { return m_floatSet; }
};
```

Вызов функции:

```
SelectionManager sm;
std::set<int> set = sm.getSelectionSetPtr<int>();
```